# While retrieving data from Rest API its alter me twice at a time in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, restful-url

```
var hsbc = angular.module('hsbc',['ngResource','ngRoute']);

hsbc.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){   

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })
        .when('/gloabltranfer', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/gloabltranfer.html'
        })
        .when('/tranferReq', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/TransferRquest.html'
        })
        .when('/reviewdetail', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/Reviewdetails.html'
        })
        .when('/confirmdetail', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/confirmdetails.html'
        })

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

}]).controller('hsbccontroller', ['$scope','$http','$resource','$location', function($scope,$http,$resource,$location){

    var gformcountry, gtocountry, userID;

    $scope.hsbcacct = [];
    $scope.countries = [];
    $scope.login = function(){
        var username = $scope.username;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        if(username =='test' && pass =='test'){
            username = 1;
            //$location.path('/gloabltranfer');
        }
        else if(username =='test2' && pass =='test2'){
                username = 2;
                $location.path('/gloabltranfer');
                }
        else{
                $location.path('/login');
        }
    }

    $http.get('json/currency.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.countries = data;
        });
    $scope.countryFromTo = function(){
        var formData = { 'fromcountry':$scope.fromcountry };        
    }

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestWebServices/rest/AccountService/getAccount').success(function(data){
            alert(data.accountName);
            $scope.hsbcaccts = data;
    });
     $http.get('http://localhost:8080/1/').success(function(data) {
            //alert(data.accountIds);
            $scope.hsbcaccts = data;
     });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/1/recipients').success(function(data) {
           // alert(data.accountIds);
            $scope.recieveraccs = data;
     });

}]);
```

While retrieving data from Rest API its alter me twice at a time in angularJS?

Its retrieving data twice. I'm getting alter 2 time alert  (data.accountName).

Info: Same time it's working perfectly in IE.

Comment: Try to check you Network tabs at developper tools, and make sure that the file is only called one time

Comment: Its called twice. but wrote for one time.

Comment: Most probably there are two controllers loaded in memory, each one calling alert. You can verify it by checking the `$scope.$id` on each callback. Have you used the same controller in route config and ng-controller declaration

Comment: Added full code here

Comment: without controller i cant change my location.path in angular. plzz anyone help me make it.

Answer (score 1):

In the template you declare the controller with "ng-controller"?
If you declare the controller in the template and also in the routes you will be loaded twice. I was wrong I also a lot of times :)

Comment: without controller i cant change my location.path

Answer (score 0):

You said that the file is called twice time, then use [angularJs promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Because according to the official documention:

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.

Then, you can do a test, if the returned value is empty or not.

This [video](http://www.grafikart.fr/formations/angularjs/promesses) (french video) talk about promise. It can helps you to understand how promise works.

Comment: without controller i cant change my location.path in angular. plzz anyone help me make it.